# Fitting of distributions

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, fitting

I have a dataset containing 50 datapoints to which I need to fit some non-standard continuous distributions (the functional form is known) using maximum likelihood estimation. I presume there are functions like 'optim' or 'nlm' in R that do the job. However, I would like to know how to choose the starting parameter vector in these procedures.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is [Convex](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexFunction.html) (or can be represented in a convex manner), then the initial point doesn't matter.

Else, a common strategy is to choose a random initial point, and do a **random restart** every time the optimization algorithm converges, Then take the highest parameter set of all the iterations.

Comment: My function is convex, but does the initial point really not matter during optimization ?

Comment: If its convex, then it has only one minimum, thus the algorithm cannot converge to a local minimum and the initial point should not matter (as long as there were enough iterations for convergence)